# Converting input from argv[ ] into a char?

Tags: c++, c, argv

I am creating a program that will run with a file name.

Example:

./program filename.txt

I am having difficulty with the following error:

```
error: array type 'char [20]' is not assignable
```

This is the code that I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char filename[20];
    filename = argv[1];
}
```

How would I convert the input from `argv[]` into the char array that I have?

Comment: Is this C or C++? If it's C++, use `std::string`.

Comment: Why don't you just use `argv[1]` as your file-name? Do you have any intentions of changing it???

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are not assignable

Use

```
strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
```

Comment: No, don't use that. This does nothing to protect against `argv[1]` being longer than fits in `filename`.

Comment: @hvd; Neither `strncpy`!

Comment: @haccks I didn't suggest to use `strncpy`. It could be used, but it wouldn't be the best way to go. I generally like the non-standard `strlcpy`, which can easily be implemented portably for systems that don't have it. (Actually, thinking some more, I really don't think there's anything to do here. Truncating file names is bad. If a fixed-length buffer is needed, and the file name doesn't fit in it, an error should be emitted.)

Comment: @hvd The point was to mention arrays are not assignable nothing wrong using strcpy() but I agree that care needs to taken about the length.

Comment: @hvd; That means answer is not wrong any way. Standard provides only two functions for string copy. I do not suggest to go with a non standard function.

Comment: @haccks If you prefer making your program susceptible to buffer overflows because you don't want to write your own function that protects against those, then fine, but I hope I never have to use code you've written.

Comment: @hvd; Its matter of taste and requirements.

Comment: @hvd Yes you can write your own function but you can't down-vote and say this is wrong. This does answer the question standard supports it. If we look at it that way then for each answer here we need to care of multiple checks if not every answer turns out to be wrong.

Comment: @Gopi I did, so clearly I can. It does answer the question that's asked, but it does so in a way that's more harmful than helpful, which is something that I definitely do downvote for, and intend to continue doing.

Comment: @hvd ok I take it. Its your opinion. Then any usage of strcpy() is wrong

Comment: @Gopi No, that's not what I'm saying. Using `strcpy()` can be fine if you know the destination is large enough. If you know the string length in advance, `memcpy` will probably do a better job, but if you copy a string where you know the length to be at most N into a buffer capable of storing a string of length N, then `strcpy` is fine.